# creating xpath with two conditions

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

guys!
I am learning xpath and collided with an issue;

[image: html]:

and there are many `<li class="sport--block">...</li>`

I found class, which I need by this:

```
var numOfGames = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/li[contains(div/span, 'Теніс')]
```

How can I add the second condition and check each `event--line--position` and get span values for all of them.

I need check each `event--line--position` under my `<li class="sport--block">...</li>`. I bet it has to be one query.

Shall I create loop or can it be implemented at once and add values to list?
THanks a lot for investing your time for me.

Comment: this xpath also doesn't help me:  var numOfGames = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='sport--list']/li[contains(div/span, 'Теніс')]/ul/li/ul/li/div/div/div/div/span"));

Answer (score 2):

Try `//ul[@class='sport--list']/li[contains(div/span, 'Теніс')]//div[@class='event--line--position']/span`

Comment: I tried to use it, but I got an exception: +  $exception {"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"//ul[@class='sport--list']/li[contains(div/span, 'Теніс')]//div[@class='event--line--position']/span\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.170)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)"} OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException

Comment: I used this line:    var numOfGames = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='sport--list']/li[contains(div/span, 'Теніс')]//div[@class='event--line--position']/span"));